# Python Regex: Pulling the latest date from a string

Tags: python, regex, date

I have the following string:

```
text = '3 Day Pass Tickets (September 27 - September 29 - 21+ Event)'
```

and my end goal is to pull out the latest date (September 29) using regex. This is just an example, but in all cases, the latest date will always come last. Using the following expression

```
eventdate = re.search(r'(January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December) \d\d?', text)
```

results in

```
eventdate.group() = 'September 27'
```

How can I alter the regex to capture only 'September 29'?

Thanks!

Comment: `re.findall` instead ?

Comment: Expected output for: `'(September 27 - October 21  September 29)'`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`re.findall`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) instead, and retrieve the last matched string.

```
>>> pattern = r'((?:January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December) \d\d?)'
>>> re.findall(pattern, text)[-1]
'September 29'
```

Comment: Great call, I didn't think to use findall. This works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `re.search` like this:

```
>>> result = re.search(r'.*((?:January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December) \d\d?)', text)
>>> print(result.group(1))
September 29
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/cV2rR8)

I added the `.*` at the start of the regex so that its greedy nature will 'eat' all up to the end and backtrack to get the last match.

And put the part you want in a capture group (while turning the months in a non-capture group).

Also, you might use something like this for the months:

```
(?:(?:Jan|Febr)uary|Ma(?:rch|y)|April|Ju(?:ne|ly)|August|(?:Septem|Octo|Novem|Decem)ber)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your string always looks like that, in addition to using re.findall, you can also do:

```
eventdate = re.search(r'(.* - January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December) \d\d?', text)
eventdate.group()
```

This results in:

```
'September 27'
```

Comment: This won't do. You have to backtrack from the end but leave the cuantifier out of any grouping.

Comment: You're right. Wouldn't this work, simply based on the fact that the first date doesn't have a space in front of it, but the second does? (Assuming that will always be true). There's a single space at the beginning of the regular expression:


    eventdate = re.search(r' (January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December) \d\d?', text)